# Adding a C wire or Google Power Connector to an old Lennox furnace

Tags: furnace, thermostat-c-wire

As the title suggests I am looking for advice on connecting a C wire or hooking up a Google Power Connector (I have it already) to my furnace.

I have a Lennox G803, it already has a humidifier attached as well as a Hoym air control thing (it's hard to read). I think I know what to do but I would really appreciate your input.

[image: furnace schematics]

[image: main furnace part]

[image: overview picture]

[image: Power box note the transformer at the bottom for the hunidifier]

Answer below from Jasen :)

Comment: Glad you got this working! Since you took the [tour], you know that this place works a little differently than others. Instead of editing your original question to say "thanks", the appropriate thing to do is click the up arrow next to any and all answers that helped you, the click the check mark next to the answer that helped you the _most_. Also, it's preferred that you write up an answer of your own (self-answers are 100% acceptable) if you want to share the results of what you did. After all, if the answer is in the question, there's no point in reading the answers...

Comment: I tried to upvote the answer but I don't have enough karma to do so. I was also going to reply with an answer but there was encouragement from the site NOT to do that and instead comment on other people's answer. I commented on their answers but that won't let you post a photo so that's why I edited my original post to include the image. I tried FreeMan!! I tried!!

Comment: you should have enough points to vote now. Plus you'll get 2 more for clicking the check mark by the one that helped you the most!

Comment: Yep, I am going to re-edit, and change my update to an answer and remove it from the original. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red cable that exits to the right of the picture is worrying as it seems to bypass the flue safety device.

According the the diagram C is blue wire between the gas valve and the transformer

[image]

so these are your "R" "W" and "C" connections
[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. I am going to look into the Hoyme air intake thing and find its diagram. It was setup by the previous owners. I will add that the way they twisted in the wires was not great either. I've added my final pics up top! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One of these two terminals on your control transformer is the C wire terminal. If you have a voltmeter, you can measure each terminal on the transformer against the R terminal. The C terminal will give you 24v, the other 0v (or close to zero). Of you don't have a voltmeter, you can simply use trial and error. You can't hurt the thermostat.

[image]

Comment: Yep that's what I thought too though I opted to go with what Jasen said above!! Thank you

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense since that's where the rest of the thermostat wiring resides. Guess I should have looked at the wiring diagram. I went for the easy win. 

Comment: All good :) it was still helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all who helped. /u/Jasen helped me sort it perfectly. Below is the end result

The key was the blue wire :)

[image: End result]